# One To One Object Member Is Null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am learning Entity Framework. In my database, I have the following tables

**Movie Table**

```
TABLE [dbo].[movies](
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [director] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [genreId] [int] NULL )
```

**Genre Table**

```
TABLE [dbo].[genres](
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
   [category] [varchar](50) NULL
```

So the `genreId` column in `Movies` is a simple lookup to the corresponding `id` column in `Genres`

I am trying to get this association configured in Entity Framework. This is my Movie class:

```
[Table("movies")]
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int genreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("genreId")]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

}
```

And this is my Genre class:

```
[Table("genres")]
public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

}
```

When I query a Movie, the Genre member is null. I can't figure out why?

Comment: You need to make `Genre` virtual, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking at this question, I solved the problem by adding the `include` method

```
context.Movies
       .Include(m => m.Genre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Public virtual genre genre {get;set;} 
Virtual keyword let EF to create a class, also called proxy classes, at run time and set the relation as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 types of loading in the Entity Framework: eager, lazy and explicit. You need to load referenced object. Please read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

However the easiest solution is to define `public virtual Genre Genre{get;set}` to allow lazy loading.